# "He makes" us vs "he wants to make us"

Tags: sentence-usage

Can I say this either way?

> The habit he wants to make us change is recommended.
>   The habit he makes us change is recommended.

Comment: **Habit** is an unlikely word in this context, *whatever* "habitual activity" it refers to, because your *habits* are usually things you're accustomed to doing *because you feel like doing them*, not because they're "recommended".

Comment: Is this modification  OK ?

This is habit he wants to make us change .

Comment: As I said, it's unlikely. Take a typical "habit", such as smoking cigarettes. Your doctor probably wouldn't say *"I want you to change your habit of smoking"* - he'd say *"I want you to **quit smoking**"*. I think you should edit your question to clarify exactly what kind of "habit" you have in mind (and what kind of "change"). In most cases, any "change" to a habit actually nets down to either starting/adopting it, or stopping/quitting. Particularly if they're the kind of habits that might be either recommended or advised against.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to say, _"He wants us to change our habits."_ That would be regarded as acceptable.

Comment: Thank you.   PS I try to remember that " context is everything"

Comment: As a general point, there's a difference between wanting to do something and doing it.  That difference applies to these two sentences as well.

Answer (score 1):

> The habit he wants to make us change is recommended.

This sounds like someone is trying to change your (plural) habit, but your (plural) current *habit* is recommended.

If you are trying to say the *change* is recommended, say

> The change he wants us to make to our habit is recommended.
>
> The change of habit he wants us to make is recommended.
>
> He is recommending that we *change our habits* to do X instead of Y.

which makes more sense.  As @FumbleFingers says, "habits" are not something that are usually "recommended" - because changing habits is not easy and getting them is typically not voluntary.